# Passing the user name from ADF to notebooks

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

I want to pass the logged in user name from Azure Data Factory to azure notebook.

I tried dbutils functionality but no luck.

x=str(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().tags().apply('user'))
print (x)

Tried above code in notebook. When I am running the notebook directly it is giving the expected result. But from ADF it is not working

Comment: How you executed above code in ADF? Any error details?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you **can't**.

In DataFactory when you create linked service to Databricks you specify personal access token to ADF. This means all requests made from ADF are executed as that user, but there is currently no user logged in the databricks platform and as such no context is initialized.

[image]

In ADF there isn't even user variable because pipelines are designed (expected) to be executed via schedule or event triggers or external systems. Not by users manually.

Here is the list of available system variables
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables